# How to use linq with datatable and bind to the repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, linq, menu, repeater, submenu

I am trying to create a menu using linq. I am getting all menu items in dataset. I would like to show like this:

```
Main Menu Item 1
-Sub Menu
-Sub Menu
Main Menu Item 2
-Sub Menu
-Sub Menu
```

How can i use linq to sort data like this? All data stored in dataset. I want to show filtered data  in repeater.

Note: Main Menu Items have: parent_menu_id='0'

```
<ul>
<asp:Repeater runat="trepeat" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <li>
       <a href="<%# Eval("url") %>"><%# Eval("menu_name") %></a>
       <ul>
         <li>
             <a href="<%# Eval("url") %>"><%# Eval("menu_name") %></a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Comment: how does the types of those items look like? could you share your code?

Comment: @kebek i added code. sub menu <ul> stays in same <li> tag. I think we gonna need to add second repeater?

Comment: can we make infinity sub menu?

Comment: Nothing can be infinite on a PC - what exactly are you trying to say? Can you show your dataset? Do you want to run over a single query or run sub-queries for each top-level?